# Mechanics & mechanical engineering

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If an object free fall to Earth from very far distance much larger than Earth radius, time taken to complete first 1/2 of journey is approximately 9/11 of time spent for whole journey. How to prove it? I managed only to show that instant acceleration is directly proportional to instant velocity to power of 4 divided by 4. I also manage to show that total time taken of free fall is directly proportional to instant velocity to power of 3/2. I try to use calculus but it is too confusing. Your answer with all steps will be highly appreciated.